# Figure out if reflected field is volatile

Tags: c#, reflection, volatile

I'm trying to mine information from an assembly using reflection, and one of the things I'd like to know (give that it is actually a thing to know) is if a field is volatile or not. In other words, if I have the following class

```
public class Test {
    public volatile int Counter = 0;
}
```

is there any way I can (with reflection) figure out that the `Test.Counter` field is indeed volatile? Or is that simply not exported at all?

Comment: I believe it can detected from `FieldInfo.GetRequiredCustomModifiers()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`GetRequiredCustomModifiers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.getrequiredcustommodifiers.aspx) method:

```
var field = typeof(Test).GetField("Counter");
bool isVolatile = field
    .GetRequiredCustomModifiers()
    .Any(x => x == typeof(IsVolatile));
```

Comment: What do you mean by *reflection-only context*? You could use reflection to determine if a given member has the `volatile` modifier. Wasn't that what you were asking for in your question?

Comment: He's asking if this would work if the assembly containing the type in question has been loaded in a reflection-only context, say with `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad`.

Comment: Yes, and I tired to accept your answer, cause it answered my question perfectly, but I have to wait some minutes. However, I just wondered if you could do this if you load the assembly using `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad` (reflection-only context iirc), cause you can't access custom attributes then. Though I guess I'll just have to try it out :)

Comment: @Alxandr I tested this whith an assembly loaded in reflection-only context (I loaded it with `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(@"path")`), and it **works fine** even in that situation. On the other hand, `field.GetCustomAttributes(false)` throws an `InvalidOperationException`, so you're right custom attributes can't be seen in that context. Something else: The last line in above answer uses LINQ extension method `.Any`, but LINQ also has an extension method `.Contains` which is suitable here, so last line in answer could be simplified to `.Contains(typeof(IsVolatile));`.